# how to ask the user to enter a text for encryption in java code

Tags: java, security, encryption, cryptography

i have this java code , its encrypt only a given text witch is already written in the code 
how i can edit this code to make the program ask the user to enter the text and then do the encryption for the text and show the final result ? i tried to replace the text `("NagaSakti")`; and `("bismillah");` with `(System.in);` but it did not work !! please help me

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.spec.AlgorithmParameterSpec;
import java.security.spec.KeySpec;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEParameterSpec;



public class DesEncrypter {
  Cipher ecipher;


    // 8-byte Salt
    byte[] salt = {
        (byte)0xA9, (byte)0x9B, (byte)0xC8, (byte)0x32,
        (byte)0x56, (byte)0x35, (byte)0xE3, (byte)0x03
    };

    // Iteration count
    int iterationCount = 19;
    public static final DesEncrypter NAGASAKTI = new DesEncrypter("NagaSakti");

    private DesEncrypter(String passPhrase) {
        try {
            // Create the key
            KeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(passPhrase.toCharArray(), salt, iterationCount);
            SecretKey key = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(
                "PBEWithMD5AndDES").generateSecret(keySpec);
            ecipher = Cipher.getInstance(key.getAlgorithm());


            // Prepare the parameter to the ciphers
            AlgorithmParameterSpec paramSpec = new PBEParameterSpec(salt, iterationCount);

            // Create the ciphers
            ecipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, paramSpec);

        } catch (java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
        } catch (java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException e) {
        } catch (javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        } catch (java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        } catch (java.security.InvalidKeyException e) {
        }
    }

    public String encrypt(String str) {
        try {
            // Encode the string into bytes using utf-8
            byte[] utf8 = str.getBytes("UTF8");

            // Encrypt
            byte[] enc = ecipher.doFinal(utf8);

            // Encode bytes to base64 to get a string
            return new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encode(enc);
        } catch (javax.crypto.BadPaddingException e) {
        } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        }
        return null;
    }



    public static void main(String args[]){
       String encrypted = DesEncrypter.NAGASAKTI.encrypt("bismillah"); 
        System.out.println("Enter your text");  


      System.out.println("encrypted text=  "+ encrypted);

    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the Scanner class.
Add this import:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

Then in your main method do this:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter your text");  
    String textToEncrypt = keyboard.next();

    String encrypted = DesEncrypter.NAGASAKTI.encrypt(textToEncrypt);

    System.out.println("encrypted text=  "+ encrypted);
}
```

If you want to use a passphrase other than NagaSakti then change the line starting with String encrypted... to

```
System.out.println("Enter your pass phrase");  
String passPhrase = keyboard.next();
String encrypted = new DesEncrypter(passPhrase).encrypt(textToEncrypt);
```

Note you'll also have to change the DesEncrypter constructor to public to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Console` for reading passwords. Your `main` method could look like this:

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
  Console console = System.console();
  if (console == null)
    throw new IllegalStateException("console required");
  char[] password = console.readPassword("Enter your text: ");
  DesEncrypter encrypter = new DesEncrypter(new String(password));
  String encrypted = encrypter.encrypt("bismillah");
  System.out.println("encrypted text =  " + encrypted);
}
```

Using the `Console` class' specialized API has a few advantages.

First, you don't echo the password to the screen. This helps protect it from shoulder-surfing bandits.

Also, the password is returned as a character array, so that the application can fill the array with zeros or random characters when use of the password is complete. This minimizes the chance that it will be written to disk due to paging, or included in a heap dump, etc.

Finally, using the correct high-level API makes it crystal clear what your code is doing, taps into any future improvements to the feature, and simplifies your application.

There are a number of other problems with the encryption used, and I don't recommend anyone use the code as-is, but I have focused on the question posed.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
  //  open up standard input
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

  String textFromUser = null;

  //  read the text from the command-line; need to use try/catch with the
  //  readLine() method
  try {
     textFromUser = br.readLine();
  } catch (IOException ioe) {
     System.out.println("IO error trying to read your text!");
  }
```